# how to show message sent by my app in default message application

Tags: java, android

My application allows users to send messages to others, so i was wondering is it possible to show the text sent in the default message app. I want to show the text in the existing conversation in the messaging app if its possible instead of creating a new conversation.

Comment: Btw am using the standard smsManager to send the message

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Google Cloud Messaging ( GCM )](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/instachat/). This link has a nice tutorial!

Comment: am talking about normal sms messages not a chatting app